# How do I update a field (using jquery or javascript) after editing it's value on the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, shopping-cart

I have a cart implemented and after someone adds an item to the cart they can change the quantity and click update to make the required changes. However, after it has been clicked I want it to say UPDATED!

And now if someone clicks on the field again to update it. It should change back to a button that says update.

How do I do this? I'm not very familiar with jquery or javascript

Thank you.

Comment: You will generally get a better response on SO if you share some code with things you have tried and the problems that you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you are firing the server updates, but here is a short snippet which you might be able to use:

```
    $('document').ready(function(){

       $('#yourInputField').change(function() {

           $('#yourButton').addClass('enable');

        });

         $('#yourButton').on("click",function() {

          //Fire ajax for server, onsuccess is ajax success method
           onsuccess(e){
           $(this).removeClass('enable');
           $(this).addClass('disable');
           };

        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks! So I have something like that but since I'm using an update method to change the values, and that update method has a redirect_to. The changes are no longer reflected. How do I update the value and see it without redirecting to the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example to get you started:

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <input class="amount" type="text" />
    <div class="update">
        <button class="update-button" type="button">Update</button>
        <div class="update-message">Updated!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.update-button').click(function () {
    // Hide the update button
    $(this).hide()
    // Show the update message
    $(this).siblings('.update-message').show();
});

$('.amount').click(function () {
    // Show the update button
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.update-button').show();
    // Hide the update message
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.update-message').hide();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYYHz/)